# Advantages of LibCloud over Puppet for provisioning servers

Tags: python, ruby, puppet

Why would you use LibCloud rather than Puppet for provisioning servers (besides the fact that you might prefer Python over Ruby)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example of using Chef with LibCloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673599/example-of-using-chef-with-libcloud)

Comment: Yes. @coffee-grinder, it may to wait a little before you ask your subsequent question, if it is in a different form.